# Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$y = x, y = 0, x = 4, x = 7; about x = 1$$

I'm having trouble figuring out what the Outer and Inner radius are. Here is an image of the graph:

http://www.webassign.net/waplots/f/6/577a113de6db59f94f52d5dec92838.gif

I was assuming the inner radius would be a horizontal line from the axis of rotation (x = 1) to x = 4, and the outer radius would be a horizontal line from the axis of rotation (x = 1) to x = 7.

With that in mind, outer  radius = 7-1 and inner radius = 4 - 1. And so we integrate from bottom to top (from 0 to 7)

But that doesn't seem right because then my integral looks like

$$\pi \int_0^7 6^2 - 3^2 \, dy$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner radius of the volume is not constant, so it will not always be $4 - 1 = 3$. But the outer radius will always be $7 - 1 = 6$, so you have that right.

You need to take into account the fact that for $y \geq 4$, the lower bound on $x$ (or equivalently, the inner radius of the volume) is defined by the curve $y = x$, not the $y$-axis. If you want to integrate over $dy$, you would need to separate your calculation into two integrals: one for the region when $0 \leq y \leq 4$ and one for the region when $4 \leq y \leq 7$.

Alternatively, you may use the shell method to compute this using a single integral, assuming you have already covered it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I set up the integral using cylindrical shells?

Comment: Each shell would have a particular radius, height, and width. In this case, the radius lies in the $x$ direction, so the radius of each shell for $x \in [4,7]$ is $x - 1$, as we are rotating around $x = 1$. Next, we look at the height. For any $x \in [4,7]$, the height of the shell is bounded by the curves $y = x$ and the $x$-axis, so the height is simply $x - 0 = x$. Finally, since the radius is along the $x$ direction, the width is $dx$. Thus, the volume of a single shell is $2\pi rhdx = 2\pi(x - 1)x dx$. Now it is just a matter of integrating this over $[4,7]$.

Comment: Thanks I had figured that out, except I was integrating over [4,6] instead of 4,7 because I'm blind so the answer kept coming out wrong. Thank you!